# SharePoint Server 2013 Foundation Web/App Server two network adapters

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is this scenario supported by Microsoft and make sense?

- SharePoint 2013 Foundation Web/App Server will have one adapter with public and one adapter with private IP Address?
- Routing between two adapters will be configured.
- SharePoint Server will have connection to SQL using internal adapter (private IP)
- Firewall will be on SharePoint Server from Windows configured

What are the security and configuration concerns here?

Answer (score 2):

Your scenario will be supported, but it's not a very good one from a security perspective. SharePoint is not designed to be exposed directly to the internet.

You should publish SharePoint externally via [WebApplicationProxy](http://www.brightstarr.com/sharepoint-technology-and-application-insights/securely-publishing-sharepoint-externally-using-web-application-proxy) or even better [AzureAD Application Proxy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-proxy-enable-remote-access-sharepoint). This can also save a lot of pain regarding to external sharing (Improved security, nice login-form for users, access to OfficeWebApps-Server, option to activate a 'change password' feature, ...). It's a little bit of work, but it's absolutely worth the implementation-effort.

Two more tipps:

- If you still want to keep your structure, you do not nee to enable routing between adapters.
- Use the same URL for internal and external access (e.g. sharepoint.company.com - NO sharepoint.company.local).