# Installing SharePoint in a different domain than SQL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server, trusted-domain

There are two domains, **DomainA** and **DomainB** in my environment. Is it possible that i can install SharePoint in **DomainA** and SQL server in **DomainB** without having the trust relationship between both domains?

The domains difference is because one of our domain is for DMZ and the other is for MZ.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. You need to have the trust relationship between both domains.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically possible, even if i absolutely cannot recommend it.

You can use SQL Server Accounts for SharePoint instead of Domain Accounts. I made a Microsoft Ticket several Years ago for SharePoint Server 2016 for this question. The answer was: Supported scenario. But no one was able to give us any guarantee if every feature will be available for this setup.

Nevertheless... I think your desired architecture is bad practice. You plan to put SharePoint to DMZ and SQL in regular network. Better approach: Place both systems in internal network and publish SharePoint with a reverse proxy. There are several available, my recommendation is a WebApplication Proxy or (cloud approach) use an Azure AD Application Proxy.

Some references:

[SharePoint 2013 farm in a DMZ with ADFS/proxy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258384/sharepoint-2013-farm-in-a-dmz-with-adfs-proxy)

[SharePoint 2013 on premise - using Azure AD Application Proxy](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/237750/sharepoint-2013-on-premise-using-azure-ad-application-proxy)

[SharePoint Server 2013 Foundation Web/App Server two network adapters](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236766/sharepoint-server-2013-foundation-web-app-server-two-network-adapters)

Comment: The farm should reside on the internal network, not DMZ. Given SharePoint's reliance on Active Directory, you're having to open numerous ports in a back channel firewall unless you extend your domain into the DMZ (and note that SharePoint needs a _writable_ DC). Put a [pre-auth] Reverse Proxy in the DMZ and route your traffic that way, or as you said, AAD App Proxy if you have P1 licensing.